# Closed analytic form of $\int x^x\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have been struggling to find a closed analytic form for the indefinite integral:
$$
\int x^x\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
After a number of failed attempts I am thinking that only a numerical solution exists given bounded limits of integration.

Main attempt is integration by parts but this yields more and more integrals of form $\int x^{x+i}\,\mathrm{d}x$ (along with other complicated terms involving $\ln{x} $) for values of $i=1,2,3\ldots$.

Using Mathematica and testing various domains of $x$ I see that for $x < 0$ definite integrals are complex values.  For $x\geq0$, definite integral is bounded only by bounded upper limit of integration.

Question:  is there an analytic form for this integral.  If not, is there a good way to prove that no such analytic form exists?

Comment: I'm sure if there is a closed form, you will find that on the wiki page of [sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: That is closed for definite integral, not indefinite.  Doing the definite integral is a bit easier for given limits.

Comment: Generalized closed form for indefinite integral : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: I just looked at the Risch Algorithm and played around with the approach.  It involves finding another function $f$ to use as an integrating function in a more complicated integrand.  Now, $f$ could be anything or there could be no such $f$.  But, I haven't had time to do anything with it yet.  Today I am painting doors.

Answer (score 0):

Given the references in comments about the Sophomore Dream function, I am assuming that the answer to my question is that "No, there is no closed form analytic function whose derivative is $x^x$.

I had never heard of this "Sophomore's Dream" function before.  I came across this particular problem having already solved the derivative of $x^x$ by two different methods.  One by a trick and the other by treating the $x^x$ function as $f(x,y)=y^x$ and then taking the derivative $df$ evaluated at the point $(x,x)$.  This second method I am not even sure if it is a valid general method though I came up with the same answer.

Having done the derivative, I naturally attempted the integral of $x^x$ and failing in my attempt.